# How to create this just in normal map

Tags: texturing, normal-map

I have raised this question before but I think I did not specify enough and couldn't get what I needed. So here is the tire of a bicycle. The first image is an already modeled example of the little grappling extrusions for the tire(the extrusions are modeled). My aim is to create this effect by a normal map, like the one in the second example, but I'm not sure how. I really do not have enough experience with normal maps but it is a must for me to create it through a normal map. I hope I explained clearly what is the deal here. Appreciate all suggestions.

Important note: Neither of the images is my work. They are just guides/ examples

[image: Modeled tire example].

[image: Normal map example]

Comment: Hi :). Baking normals surely has a lot of tutorials on YT. Do these not work for you? What exactly are you stuck at? :)

Comment: As Jachym says there are lots of videos online about this. Try [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kg0wIBIpGG0) by PIXXO 3D which is for Blender 2.8 but the technique is very similar for later versions.

Comment: I know, I am watching a lot of tutorials right now and posting only if I struggle on finding or figuring out something:) But I was not sure how to approach it. Should I look at baking normals?

Comment: I think Jason got what I was looking for. I am kind of bunt out by the process and didn't know how to find out what I was looking for I guess. Thank you so much!